# How does the .reduce() function work with Math.max() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, eloquent

Can I get some help in understanding how the reduce function works in conjunction with Math.max() here?

```
function rowHeights(rows){
    return rows.map(function(row){
        return row.reduce(function(max,cell){
            return Math.max(max, cell.minHeight());
        },0);
    });
}
```

The code if from the book
[Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html)

Answer (score 4):

I'll explain what this does line by line :)

```
 1    function rowHeights(rows) {
 2        
 3        return rows.map(function(row) {
 4            
 5            return row.reduce(function(max,cell) {
 6                return Math.max(max, cell.minHeight());
 7            },0);
 8            
 9        });
10    
11    }
```

- Line 1: Declares `function rowHeights`, which takes an argument `rows`, a 2-dimensional array.
- Line 3: Calls [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the `rows` array, which essentially calls a function on each of the array elements within `rows` and replaces each element with the returned value of the function call
- Line 5: On each of the sub-arrays (rows) within the array `rows`, call [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), which calls a function on each element to reduce the sub-array into a single element.
- Line 5: Notice that there are 2 parameters for this function, `max` and `cell`.  Think of these values as `previous` and `current` values for now
- Line 6: Compare the previous (`max` parameter) value with the current (`cell` parameter) value using [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max).  Return the higher of the two.
- Line 7: The second argument to `Array.prototype.reduce` is set to `0`.  This means that on the very first iteration, the initial value of `max` is `0`.

Basically, what this does is loop through each `row` sub-array in the `rows` array.  On each iteration, it compares the value returned from the previous iteration `max` with the current value.  If the current value is larger than the previous, it returns a new `max`.  `max` is initially set to 0.  Once the `reduce` function has completed, it replaces the `row` sub-array to the value of the highest number.

This function could be also written as:

```
function rowHeights(rows) {
    var newRowsArray = [];

    for (var i = 0, tmp = 0; i < rows.length; i++, tmp = 0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < rows[i].length; j++) {
            tmp = Math.max(tmp, rows[i][j]);
        }
        newRowsArray.push(tmp);
    }

    return newRowsArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Math.max` returns the larger of its two parameters.

`.reduce` applies a transformation to every element in a collection (array) and returns a value.

In this case, the two parameters are the previous max and the current value of the cell. So, for a given row, iterate over the cells (`.reduce`) and return the largest value of `cell.minHeight()`.

---

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

[Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that you have a matrix with numbers [[31,10,23],[20,5,1],[12,31,41]]

`rows.map(function (row) {})` will iterate over each item updating the array value with the returned value from the callback function.

Example: in the first iteration we have [31,10,23]

`row.reduce(function (acumulated, current) {})` will be called three times with two arguments (**previous returned value** and **current item from array**) and will return the max between them.

```
   Math.max(0,31) = 31 
   Math.max(31,10) = 31 
   Math.max(31,23) = 31 // This is the returned value
```

the result will be the number 31. When it is returned to map function, it will be replace in the main array. So it will be something like:

```
   [31,[20,5,1],[12,31,41]]
```

and everything will repeat with [20,5,1] and [12,31,41]. All of them will have the max value at the end of all interation.

```
   [31,20,41]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to keep this explanation simple.

`Math.max(1, 5)` returns the largest number which would be 5 in this example.

Reduce basically goes through an array while passing on the previous result.  For example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].reduce(function (prevNum, currentNum) {
  return {{number to send to the next iteration as prevNum}};
});
```

So, if you put the two together, reduce will go through each number in the array and return the largest number found.

```
[1,2,3,4,5].reduce(function (prevNum, currentNum) {
  return Math.max(prevNum, currentNum);
});
```

Map will go through an array and create a new array with each index being the return value of the function passed.

```
[1,2,3,4,5].map(function (currentNum) {
  return currentNum + 1;
});
// this would return [2,3,4,5,6] because I added 1 to each number in the array
```

In the example from the book, the `rowHeights` function basically iterates over each row using `map`, and uses `reduce` to return the max height of a row of cells in a table.  The result from this is basically an array of max heights that I'm assuming will be used to set the min-height of each row as the author states.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the maximum value of each row as an array.  These are equivalent statements:

```
Math.max(1,2,36,9)
Math.max.apply(Math,[1,2,36,9])
[1,2,36,9].reduce(function(mx,c) { return Math.max(mx,c); } )
```

The first statement is really easy to understand.  It returns the maximum value of those 4 numbers (ie 36).  Now each of the following statements get progressively more intricate, but do the exact same thing as the first.